# Помогите написать функцию. Найти ближайшую станцию метро

Tags: python, geo

Помогите написать функцию на Python. У менять есть список (долгота и широта) станций метро. Функцию должна брать на вход долготу и широту объекта и находить из этого списка ближайшую станцию и выводить расстояние в метрах (или км).
В `list_metro` находиться координаты станций. Она возвращает коэффициенты: 3 - если расстояние до метро меньше км. , 2 - если до 2х км,и если больше 2х - 1. Вот  функция. Но она показывает неправильные результаты если сравнивать с гуглом. Помогите ее исправить. Спасибо.

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

def metro_distance(lat1, long1): 
    list_dist = []
    for i in list_metro:
        lat1 =  radians(lat1)
        long1 = radians(long1)
        lat2 = radians(i[0])
        long2 = radians(i[1])

        dlong =  long2 - long1
        dlat = lat2 - lat1
        g = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlong / 2)**2
        c = 2 * asin(sqrt(g))

        r = 6371   # Radius of earth in kilometers.
        dist = (c * r)

        list_dist.append(dist)
    min_dist = min(list_dist)
    if min_dist < 1.0:
        dist_coef = 3
    elif 1.0 < min_dist < 2.0:
        dist_coef = 2
    else:
        dist_coef = 1
    return dist_coef
```

Comment: dist_coef в этом коде будет 1 когда расстояние больше 2.0 или ровно 1.0

Comment: ну и так чисто по коду -  зачем каждый раз в цикле вычислать lat1 =  radians(lat1) и long1 = radians(long1), достаточно вычислить один раз перед циклом. Список list_dist тоже не нужен, единственное его предназначение - найти минимальный элемент. Это легко делается без списка.

Comment: Подозреваю, что вы считаете расстояние до центра объекта, а гугль - до ближайшего входа.

Comment: Все-таки где-то функция не так считает. Где-то в ней ошибка. min_dist выдает совсем не те цифры когда тестирую на координатах

Comment: @Alexandr формулы у вас откуда ?

Comment: формулы мне дали. но я не стал вникать правильно ли они написаны. И вот теперь понимаю, что надо было мне самому все писать и во всем рабираться

Comment: Но если может кто-то такую функцию написать, буду очень признателен)

Comment: Сравнил с картами Яндекса и Google. Совпадает расстояние посчитанное по формулам для указанных координат. Но что удивительно, у Гугла и Яндекса разные координаты по одним и тем же входам в метро. Отсюда нужно понимать с чем сравниваете. Но у Вас есть ошибка в неравенствах. Для расстояния равного 1.0 и 2.0 будет показан последний `else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного пофантазировал на тему) Разбил на две функции с поиском расстояния и поиском ближайшей станции.

Формулы расчета можно подсмотреть на Вики: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

На вход, для примера, подаю словарь станций с координатами (брал отсюда https://api.hh.ru/metro/1, но если сравнение будет с Гуглом или Яндексом, то нужны от них координаты, т.к. они немного не совпадают между сервисами, как писал в комментариях).

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin


def distance_haversine(point_1: tuple, point_2: tuple):
    d_earth = 2.0 * 6372.8
    lat1, long1 = tuple(radians(c) for c in point_1)
    lat2, long2 = tuple(radians(c) for c in point_2)
    d = sin((lat2 - lat1) / 2.0) ** 2.0 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(
        (long2 - long1) / 2.0) ** 2.0
    return d_earth * asin(d ** 0.5)


def find_nearest(point_1: tuple, points: dict):
    dists = {p: distance_haversine(point_1, points[p]) for p in points}
    name, dist = min(dists.items(), key=lambda d: d[1])
    return {'name': name, 'distance': dist,
            'dist_coef': 3 if dist <= 1.0 else 2 if dist < 2.0 else 1}


metro_points = {
    'Новокосино': (55.745113, 37.864052),
    'Перово': (55.75098, 37.78422),
    'Ховрино': (55.8777, 37.4877),
    }

point_1 = (55.741298984107324, 37.415756143334846)
print(find_nearest(point_1, metro_points))
# {'name': 'Ховрино', 'distance': 15.823760672698684, 'dist_coef': 1}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам, добрый человек! Работает!!!